# github authentication error for installing gsap-scrolltrigger in react project

Tags: reactjs, git, gsap, scrolltrigger, locomotive-scroll

so I was trying to use gsap along with locomotive scroll and scrolltrigger plugin installing gsap and locomotive was not a problem but whenever I try installing scrolltrigger using `npm install gsap gsap/ScrollTrigger` command my terminal shows error like this:-

```
info: please complete authentication in your browser...Completed in 0ms
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/gsap/ScrollTrigger.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users....
```

i want to know what am doing wrong here as i have no idea, do i need to authenticate through github?? if so how exactly

i ran the following commands:-

`npm install gsap`

`npm install locomotive-scroll`

`npm install gsap gsap/ScrollTrigger`

and i was expecting to import them in my component like this

```
import { gsap } from 'gsap';
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger';
import LocomotiveScroll from 'locomotive-scroll';

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
```